# Is there any way to read CODE39 Extended in html code reader?

Tags: javascript, barcode

I am trying to work with https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode .
IS there any way to read CODE39 Extended barcodes, with this, or another web based code reader?
I want to read the attached barcode for example:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I found this one and its work great! But I find a free one. I need license key with this one.

Comment: You might try quaggajs or one of its forks.  The original code is at https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/.  An actively maintained fork can be found at https://github.com/ericblade/quagga2.  Note that code39 extended is just code39 but interpreted differently in software.

Comment: Thanks @MarkWarren. I try the quaggajs but it cant read this code. How can I modify the Code39 to work on this barcode?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using quaggajs (the original project) on your provided image:

```
// -- commonjs usage --
const Quagga = require('quagga').default;
// -- ES6 usage --
// import Quagga from 'quagga';


Quagga.decodeSingle({
    decoder: {
        readers: ["code_39_reader"] // List of active readers
    },
    numOfWorkers: 0,  // Needs to be 0 when used within node
    locate: true, // try to locate the barcode in the image
    src: 'c:/tmp/tYlHd.jpg' // or 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data
}, function(result){
    if (result.codeResult) {
        console.log("result", result.codeResult.code);
    } else {
        console.log("not detected");
    }
});
```

The console output is:

```
result PAUT-953MAGENTA
```

That above usage is for node-js.  When using in the browser, comment out the `numOfWorkers:0` line.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you testing this on?

Have you tried this config (with the lastest library version):

```js
let html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", 
    { 
        fps: 10,
        qrbox: {width: 250, height: 250},
        useBarCodeDetectorIfSupported: true,
        rememberLastUsedCamera: true,
        aspectRatio: 4/3,
        showTorchButtonIfSupported: true
    });
```

If this doesn't work, can you verify if this one is working for you: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/tree/performance/minified

If it's still not working, please file a bug at https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/issues/new/choose with more information, and I shall look into the issue.

(Author here).